# using padding to concat two hex numbers?

Tags: python-3.x

I have to concatenate two hex numbers like below and store result in checksum:

```
crc_high = b"12"
crc_low = b"A3"
```

checksum should be `b"12A3"`

I tried the following code:

```
import operator

crc_high = b"14"
crc_low = b"7A"
checksum = b""

crc_high = crc_high.ljust(4,b"0")
# checksum = operator.or_(int(crc_high), int(b"0000"))
print(crc_high)

crc_low = crc_low[::-1].ljust(4,b"0")[::-1]
print(crc_low)

checksum = operator.or_(int(crc_high), int(crc_low))
print(checksum)
```

But I am getting error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'007A'`. It's because of `"A"`. But how do I overcome this? Plus, are there any better way for getting the same result?

Idea in my code is that to make `crc_high = b"1200"` and `crc_low = b"00A3"` and then apply bitwise operation on both result to get `b"12A3"`.

Comment: did you try `checksum = crc_high + crc_low`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo It outputs b'1400007A'. Obviously not desired.

Comment: **before** your manipulations - https://onlinegdb.com/rJ2iTlipr

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't understand what `bytes` objects are, so check out [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview). I think you're expecting them to work like `bytes.fromhex`.

As for how to solve the problem, here's one way using strings:

```
crc_high = "4"
crc_low = "A"
checksum = "{:0>2}{:0>2}".format(crc_high, crc_low)
print(checksum)  # -> 040A
```

This uses the format specifier `0>2` to zero-fill each hex number to 2 digits.